# NPM: How to update lodash when depends of jshint

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

I have passed an audit in npm and I've got this:

[image]

So, I'm trying to update lodash package but I don't know how can I do it. I have tried to do it with npm -i --save lodash, but this is not correct, because it's create another package with the latest version and not substitute the actual package which has ... version to the actual version. My actual version of lodash is 3.7.0 and I wanto to update to 4.17.5.

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm update lodash` in your project's main directory. If that doesn't work, run `npm uninstall lodash` and then `npm install lodash`.